# Terminating process created in a if condition in another if condition

Tags: python, subprocess, tcpdump

I am new to programming and working on a hobby project.
I am creating a process when a certain condition is true using subprocess module in python.

Now I want to terminate the process when the other condition is true.

```
if new_lenght>old_length:
       print("I will Record")
       process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'tcpdump', '-l', '-i', wlan_iface1, '-w',f'{new[-1]}.pcap'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
if new_lenght < old_length:
       print("I will Stop")
```

**More code**
So I am using the script I found on github https://github.com/Lynbarry/WiFinder and changing it to do bit more. The changes I made looks horrible and I also wrote some functions twice to understand it better.There are still few parts which I don't understand like the "UpdateHostList" function.But I will somehow try to it figure out as I do more editing in the code.

```
import netifaces 
import netaddr
import nmap
import re
import sys
import time
import subprocess
import os

hostList = []
gracePeriod = 1


try:
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()         # instance of nmap.PortScanner
except nmap.PortScannerError:
    print('Nmap not found', sys.exc_info()[0])
    sys.exit(0)
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    sys.exit(0)
    
def seek():
   curHosts =[]
   global wlan_iface
   ifaces=netifaces.interfaces() #Get all the avalialbe interfaces
   pattern = '^w' #Pattern maching for wlan interface
   
   for position in range(len(ifaces)):
       name = ifaces[position]
       match_result = re.match(pattern,str(name))
       if match_result:
           wlan_iface=name
   addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses(wlan_iface)
   ipinfo = addrs[netifaces.AF_INET][0]
   address = ipinfo['addr']
   wlan_iface1=str(wlan_iface)
   netmask = ipinfo['netmask']
   # Create ip object and get CIDR
   cidr = netaddr.IPNetwork('%s/%s' % (address, netmask))
   a=str(cidr)
   nm.scan(hosts = a, arguments = '-sn -T4')
   # executes a ping scan
   localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
   print('============ {0} ============\n'.format(localtime))
   for host in nm.all_hosts():

       curHosts.append((host,gracePeriod))
   curHosts.remove((str(address),gracePeriod))
   old=sniff_old()
   old_length=len(old)
   updateHostList(curHosts)
   new=sniff_new()
   new_lenght=len(new)
   if new_lenght>old_length:
       print("I will Record")
       process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'tcpdump', '-l', '-i', wlan_iface1, '-w', f'{new[-1]}.pcap'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   if new_lenght < old_length:
       print("I will Stop")
       process.kill()
       process.terminate()
       process.wait()
    
   return len(hostList)
   
def sniff_new():
    sniff_list=[]
    for host in hostList:      
       sniff_list.append(host[0])

    print(f"{sniff_list} NEW")
    return((sniff_list))
def sniff_old():
    sniff_list=[]
    for host in hostList:      
       sniff_list.append(host[0])
    old_sniff=(sniff_list)
    
    print(f"{old_sniff} OLD")
    return((old_sniff))
           
           
             
def updateHostList(curHosts):
    global hostList
    if hostList == []:
        hostList = curHosts
    else:
        hostList = [(x[0],x[1]-1) for x in hostList]
        


        # only the hosts that were new in this iteration
        newList = [(x[0],x[1]) for x in curHosts if not (any(x[0]==y[0] for y in hostList))]

        for host in newList:
            hostList.append(host)

        for host in hostList:
            if any(host[0] == y[0] for y in curHosts):
                hostList[hostList.index(host)] = (host[0],gracePeriod)

        for host in hostList:
            if host[1] <= 0:
                hostList.remove(host)
           
def beep():                         # no sound dependency
    print('\a')            
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    old_count = new_count = seek()


    startCounter = gracePeriod
    
    # are there any new hosts?
    while True:
        startCounter -= 1
        time.sleep(1)               # increase to slow down the speed
        old_count = new_count
        new_count = seek()
        

    # DANGER!!!
```

Comment: `process.kill()` will terminate the process.

Comment: Only one of those conditions can be true. If the second condition is true, you won't create the process, so there's nothing to terminate.

Comment: BTW, what do you want to do when the two lengths are exactly equal? You don't handle that in either `if`.

Comment: Thanks!! I am not sure if the process variable can be used outside scope of  the condition but I will give it a try.

Comment: Python variable scope is by function, there's no separate scope for the `if`.

Comment: If the two lengths are equal do nothing.

Comment: Ah Thanks!! Didn't knew that!

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'process' referenced before assignment

Comment: As I said before, if the second condition is true, you never execute the code that creates the process. So the variable won't be set.

Comment: Actually the conditions will be keep on changing so if a new device connects the network, new length will be greater than old length and when it leaves it will be opposite and at that time i want the terminate the process i created.

Comment: you need to post more code that shows how the variables change.

Comment: Sorry for the messy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [process.kill()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) to terminate process. Afterwards do [process.wait()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) to wait till it fully terminates. Example below.

I replaced your shell command with simple python's infinite-loop program. Just for the sake of working example that can be tested by all StackOverflowers.

In your case `for` loop is not necessary, also my shell command doesn't matter, these two modifications were done only for runnable example purpose.

Notice in second `if` that I used `'process' in locals() and process is not None`, this check is necessary in order to have no error if `process` variable wasn't yet created, in this case you don't need to kill/wait anything, because there is actually nothing to be killed/waited because there is no process created yet. Also I set variable to `process = None` so that you never do a second kill again on already killed process.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDBSgMxFLzvVzx7SQKxUIoIRQUPHnqRot5KkXWTusH4Xkjesvj162arEmw7h5CXYebNJHxxS7gcBvcZKDKk7i1EamxK1Z4ioO1fvcX3ljWQN9OdW3AIW3mt4UppkEsNi4XarSoY4faFBu4K0YHPCNEhy9kaeuc9PNmGopmpgp72w20RZr6hYFFuRZjyCg3issln3zpv4SV2dgWhTkns9J9RRmJDHf/zWm8e1Im0N2XFGg2IH4XIhT01tU9STcxvRpcAieGR0J7r98wUjtvNP0ZOHj/3tWN56i/yiurgLO5HWzPOF0INwzc)

```py
import subprocess
for new_lenght, old_length in [(7, 5), (3, 11)]:
    if new_lenght > old_length:
        print("I will Record")
        process = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'while True: pass'],
            stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    if new_lenght < old_length and 'process' in locals() and process is not None:
        print("I will Stop")
        process.kill()
        process.wait()
        process = None
print('All done!')
```

Output:

```
I will Record
I will Stop
All done!
```

Comment: I am definitely doing something wrong then in my code.

Comment: @jaysoni Why do you think that you're doing wrong? Just add two lines `process.kill()` and `process.wait()` and that's it. Nothing else needed from my code example. Only these two lines are needed for your code. If you have some errors then please post error message here in this comments. If there is no error so then why do you think that your code is not working now? I made bigger example just for the sake of showing working code to other StackOverflowers, for you only these two lines (`kill` and `wait`) are needed.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'process' referenced before assignment` @Arty

Comment: @jaysoni To solve this error just add extra if testing presence of this variable, in other words add extra `if 'process' in locals():`, as [in this code](https://tio.run/##bcsxDsIwDIXhvaewujRZWNgQF2DmACgqLrEwdpRYijh9iNKRenv@9aWvRZVza7SBYH0wyisaXEH5OYbFywT9UiYxN9@gEjPcTdPsp1G6XFLWFUtZgARY18DF@d3tdtTTu1Pn/96G@UMSDA9aDWTOt/YD) snippet. I will post you pieces of code by such web-links because inside comments you can't give a multi-line formatted piece of code.

Comment: @jaysoni If you too want to share code, then click my link (from previous comment), change code there, click on "chain" button which is shown in red [on this screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMgUY.png), then on next screen click "clipboard button" to the right from Plain URL as shown in red [on this screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdqmK.png). Now this link is copied to your clipboard, you can send this link to anyone whom you want to share code with.

Comment: I was using the if condition in the function I was calling from the main function and that's why I was having that problem.I changed my code now and its all working.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239464/discussion-between-jay-soni-and-arty).

Comment: @jaysoni If my Answer was useful to you and if it is correct, then don't forget to Up-Vote and Accept it. Both Up-Voting and Accepting is done to the left hand-side at the top of my answer, there is a Check-Mark (for Accepting) and Up-Arrow (for Up-Voting), this place where Check-Mark and Up-Arrow are located is shown in red [on this screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7lxW.png).Accepting is always needed if someone's answer is correctly answering given Question, Accept is done through "Check-Mark", Up-Vote (Up-Arrow) is needed if you Like the answer.You can do both Accept+UpVote same time

Comment: Nice way to share the code!!

Comment: @jaysoni Please come to [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239464/discussion-between-jay-soni-and-arty) if you have some other things to speak about. I'm waiting there. We can speak about the ways how to share code through web-URLs and/or how to share screen-shots.